# Generate random bytes for gpg --gen-key

Tags: shell, unix, putty, gnupg

I'm using putty to connect to a unix host where I want to generate a new gpg key.
After the Key generation started I get this message

```
Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 292 more bytes)
```

This isn't the real problem.
The real problem is now I cannot issue any more commands to the shell, it looks like this

```
dfjd
q
s
w
e
r
t
z
z
u
^_
^[[A^[[A
```

Why is this the case, no command gets executed anymore and why does the arrow up key show up as ^[[A?
How can I fix this and issue some commands that the key can get generated?

Comment: Probably better asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client system is likely waiting for randomness before it completes its connection to the remote server, hence your commands are being ignored until it can complete the connection.

Have you tried doing what the message says? Try opening up a big folder and looking at its size (on windows) or doing a `du /` (unix) to generate some disk-based randomness. Some typing may also help, depending on how your system is gathering randomness.

Knowing your client would help.

Comment: I'm using putty and the problem is that issuing commands into the shell won't do anything at this point, I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried generating more entropy on the client side, say by calculating some disk usage or a large folder? I'm guessing that putty is a windows only program.